# Error - Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js

when I run my program, I get the following error:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')
    at Proxy.mounted (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??clonedRuleSet-40.use[0]!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js??ruleSet[0].use[0]!./src/views/HdHistory.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js:563:29)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:2811:88)
    at callWithErrorHandling (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:296:18)
    at callWithAsyncErrorHandling (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:304:17)
    at hook.__weh.hook.__weh (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:2791:19)
    at flushPostFlushCbs (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:461:41)
    at flushJobs (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:499:5)
```

This is my code :

```
 mounted() {
    Promise.all([
      this.$http.get('/api/v0/tickets/divisions')
        .then((response) => {
          this.customer.items = response.data;
        }),
      this.$http.get('/api/v0/hd/groups')
        .then((response) => {
          this.groups.items.push(...response.data);
          // by default select all
          if (this.groups.selected.length === 0) this.groups.selected = this.groups.items
        }),
    ])
      .then(() => {
        this.timeScaleSelected();
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.error(e);
      });
  },
```

does anyone have any ideas?

I am trying to upgrade my program from vue2 to vue3.

Comment: Did you check the value of `this.$http`? To me it looks as if the .get method does not exist on `this.$http`

Comment: @IP002 you can even actually tell from the error that `this.$http` is `undefined`

Comment: I don't understand, what should I do instead? Because it was working before I switched to vue3 and I didn't see anything in the release notes that said something like this

Comment: I don't know vue or else I would have had an advice, while waiting for an answer, you can try to log `this` in this function in vue2 and vue3 to get clues..

Comment: There's a lot that can change when upgrading from vue 2 to vue 3.  Without any details of what the upgrade process entailed, it's impossible to say.  `$http` is a global object you created.  It's not clear what underlying library or API `$http` is linked to. How did you create it?  How did you add it to the Vue instance? Is the entire component still in Options API or are you trying to use the new Composition API? Show all relevant code.  You may also want to read about [global API breaking changes with Vue 3](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/global-api.html)

Answer (score 0):

Check your global variable in `main.js` which you're trying to use.

Vue 2 format:

```js
Vue.prototype.$http = new HTTPService();
```

Vue 3 format:

```js
const app = createApp(RootComponent)

app.config.globalProperties.$http = new HTTPService();
```

Comment: I'm not sure but I think my error comes from the "Promise.all" line because I have a similar error in another place in my code that contains a Promise.all.

Could this command have changed in the meantime?